# Jupyter Notebook doesn't show new environments

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, anaconda, jupyter-notebook

I have anaconda python 2.7 installed on my windows and I recently created a new environment for python 3.5 (using `conda create -n py35 python=3.5`).

When I `activate py35` and run `jupyter notebook`, it doesn't show py35 environment. It only has python root (py27).

How can I use this environment by jupyter ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To use jupyter notebook inside a virtual environment, `ipykernal` is required to be installed in your venv.

1. Inside your virtual environment:

   `pip install ipykernel`
2. Then run the kernel "self-install" script:

   `python -m ipykernel install --user --name=my-virtualenv-name`

Now, your new kernel has been installed.

See: [pythonanywhere](http://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/IPythonNotebookVirtualenvs)

Answer (score 5):

You can install nb_conda and it will give you Conda environment and package access extension from within Jupyter. Inside your env you can use this command:

```
conda install nb_conda
```