# Jupyter notebook doesn't see the environment's packages

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

I want to follow along a course about deeplearning. This course has a github repo, where all of the codes are available. We need to use anaconda, create an environment based on the yaml file, and run a jupyter notebook within that environment.

There's even a [test notebook](https://github.com/Dataweekends/zero_to_deep_learning_video/blob/master/course/0_Check_Environment.ipynb) to check whether the installation and environment creating process was successful. I have created the environment as the description said, the installation of the packages seemed to be good.

For the first few command, I get the required outputs, but the notebook doesn't seem to start from the correct environment, it gives me

> C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\jupyter.py

instead of

> C:\Users\paperspace\Anaconda3\envs\ztdl\lib\site-packages\jupyter.py

And it can't find the packages that I have just installed before. For example, when it has to include sklearn it gives me:

> No module named 'sklearn.__check_build._check_build'

Installing them from command line with pip/conda solves this.

I have tried to install manually **ipykernel**, **nb_conda**, **jupyter** as [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43311844/jupyter-notebook-doesnt-show-new-environments) [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39604271/conda-environments-not-showing-up-in-jupyter-notebook?rq=1) say. I ran **jupyter notebook** after I activated the conda environment from the **anaconda prompt**. But none of these helped me. As I open the kernel menu, I can see that the proper ztdl anaconda environment is the active one.

I also removed anaconda from the %PATH%, and added it again afterwards with c:\Users\user\Anaconda3\ .

I have no idea what should I do to run the notebook within this given anaconda environment, so I can access the installed packages. Thanks in advance, any help is appreciated.

Comment: You have Anaconda installed, which by default has Jupyter installed in the **base** env, so you should only ever launch `jupyter notebook` from within an activated **base** environment. If you want other envs to be available as kernels, you must 1)  install `nb_conda_kernels` in **base** and 2) install `ipykernel` in each env you wish to use. Please see [the documentation](https://github.com/Anaconda-Platform/nb_conda_kernels#installation) for more details.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Conda environments not showing up in Jupyter Notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39604271/conda-environments-not-showing-up-in-jupyter-notebook)